# POST File Stream octet-stream

Tags: http, post, protocols

Can I pass "application/octet-stream" or say a word document as stream or binary via POST (http protocol) ? (yes/no)?

Comment: How *else* would you send a body...? I don't understand the question... (I'm not sure I'd describe POST as the "protocol", but that is unrelated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically yes, providing you have the proper serialization/deserialization on each end.

From what I understand, you would just post the document as raw binary: you would then need some parsing function on the other end.

But as stated previously, your question is a bit unclear...